# MySQL JOIN two tables and ORDER BY seem not use proper indexes

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, sql-order-by, limit

I am having trouble with the performance of a MySQL query. To summarize, I would like to join table A to table B, and order the results based on table two columns from table A. My approach is making a combined index on (i) the column to join table A and B on, and (ii) the two columns on which I would like to order the results. However, as soon as I join the two tables, the behavior seems unexpected, and the `ORDER BY` clause does not seem to use the index anymore.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM
    t_patent_documents A USE INDEX (idx_t_patent_documents_result_order) INNER JOIN
    t_inv_title_int_content_combined B ON A.publication_id=B.publication_id
ORDER BY
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

For table `t_patent_documents`, I have the index combined index `idx_t_patent_documents_result_order` defined as on the columns `(publication_id, language_id, result_order)`. Furthermore, `publication_id` is the primary key of `t_patent_documents`. The explain plan is as follows:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                       | key                                 | key_len | ref              | rows      | filtered | Extra                             | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|---------|------------------|-----------|----------|-----------------------------------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL             | 132162247 | 100.00   | "Using temporary; Using filesort" | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | ref  | idx_t_patent_documents_result_order | idx_t_patent_documents_result_order | 4       | B.publication_id | 1         | 100.00   | NULL                              |
```

If I do the following (without forcing the index):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM
    t_patent_documents A INNER JOIN
    t_inv_title_int_content_combined B ON A.publication_id=B.publication_id
ORDER BY
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Then the optimizer chooses to use the primary key only:

```
|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------|---------|------------------|-----------|----------|-----------------------------------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 132162247 | 100.00   | "Using temporary; Using filesort" | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | eq_ref | "PRIMARY,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_ucid,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_ucid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_ucid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_result_order" | PRIMARY | 4       | B.publication_id | 1         | 100.00   | NULL                              |
```

Now, when I do not join table B on table A, but I `ORDER BY` the three columns on which I defined the index, i.e. `(publication_id, language_id, result_order)`, it seems to pick up the indexes properly. The `key_len` here is indeed 14:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM
    t_patent_documents A USE INDEX(idx_t_patent_documents_result_order)
ORDER BY
    A.publication_id ASC,
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

This results in the following explain plan:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                                 | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|-------|---------------|-------------------------------------|---------|------|------|----------|-------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_t_patent_documents_result_order | 14      | NULL | 100  | 100.00   | NULL  |
```

Does someone understand this behaviour? Ideally, I would be able to join another table and still be able to quickly order the results.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**:
I also tried adding `publication_id` in the `ORDER BY` clause. Although from an output perspective this would not make sense at all, because the `publication_id` is unique. The query would look as follows:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM
    t_patent_documents A USE INDEX (idx_t_patent_documents_result_order) INNER JOIN
    t_inv_title_int_content_combined B ON A.publication_id=B.publication_id
ORDER BY
    A.publication_id ASC,
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

The resulting explain plan:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                       | key                                 | key_len | ref              | rows      | filtered | Extra                             | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|---------|------------------|-----------|----------|-----------------------------------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL             | 132162247 | 100.00   | "Using temporary; Using filesort" | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | ref  | idx_t_patent_documents_result_order | idx_t_patent_documents_result_order | 4       | B.publication_id | 1         | 100.00   | NULL                              |
```

***Update 2:***
I also tried running the query without the multi index on all three columns, but only on the two columns I would like to sort: `(language_id, result_order)` which is called `x_temp_idx_1`. This indeed seemed to have effect in the sense that `key_len` is 14 again, however, now the join part takes forever. The query that I ran:

```
explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE A.language_id, A.result_order
FROM
    t_patent_documents A USE INDEX(x_temp_idx_1) INNER JOIN
    t_inv_title_int_content_combined B ON A.publication_id=B.publication_id
ORDER BY
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

The corresponding explain plan:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                          | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|-------|---------------|--------------|---------|------|---------|----------|------------------------------------------------| 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | index | NULL          | x_temp_idx_1 | 14      | NULL | 1795275 | 100.00   | "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort" | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | 2469412 | 10.00    | "Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)"   |
```

Note that this query ran on another db (development) with less information. That's why the number of rows does not correspond to that of previous explain plans.

**Update 3:**
All the above queries are simplifications of the actual query I would like to run to not overcomplicate the question. In the real use case, I need to filter on a full-text index in table B. The table includes a full-text index on the column `invention_title`:

```sql
explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM
    t_patent_documents A INNER JOIN
    t_inv_title_int_content_combined B ON A.publication_id=B.publication_id
WHERE
    MATCH(B.invention_title) AGAINST("+hydraulic" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order ASC
LIMIT 100
```

The resulting explain, shows that again it uses only the primary key to do the join, but fails to use the multi-index. If I force the index again, the `key_len` is 4, and it does not actually seem to use the multi-index:

```
|    |             |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |                                                 |         |                  |      |          |                                                                      | 
|----|-------------|-------|------------|----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|---------|------------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------| 
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type     | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | key                                             | key_len | ref              | rows | filtered | Extra                                                                | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | fulltext | idx_ft_inv_title_int_content_combined_inv_title                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | idx_ft_inv_title_int_content_combined_inv_title | 0       | const            | 1    | 100.00   | "Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking; Using temporary; Using filesort" | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | eq_ref   | "PRIMARY,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_ucid,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_ucid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_pubid_country_ucid_priority_dt,idx_t_patent_documents_result_order,x_temp_idx_2" | PRIMARY                                         | 4       | B.publication_id | 1    | 100.00   | NULL                                                                 |
```

Comment: A multi-column index can be used for any prefix of the list of columns. When you don't include `publication_id` in `ORDER BY`, it can't use the index.

Comment: I actually also tried that. So if I understand you correctly, also add the `publication_id` in the `ORDER BY` clause right? Let me update the question with that explain plan as well. 1 sec.

Comment: The other option is to take `publication_id` out of the multi-column index. It's already indexed because it's the primary key.

Comment: Also tried that ;). Will update the results as well.

Comment: Is SQL_NO_CACHE still a thing? Nota bene: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Comment: Apparently yeah. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Are all joining columns the same type and length?

Comment: Yes both `publication_id` from the left and the right table are of type `int`

Answer (score 2):

For your first query, remove the `USE INDEX` and change the index to this order:

```
(language_id, result_order, publication_id)
```

The idea is to have the `INDEX` match the `ORDER BY`.  The optimizer gives preference to `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`, but you don't have either.  So, the intent *for your cases* is to be able to stop scanning after `LIMIT` rows by having the index match the `ORDER BY`.  This would work nicely for just `A`.

It may help to change the `SELECT *` to specify only the necessary rows.`

If there is exactly 1 B row for each A row, then there is another optimization.  Since this is not the case, the `JOIN` must be performed, then sort, and only finally deliver `LIMIT` rows.

re: Update 3

That is as expected.

1. Use FT index to find the (hopefully) few rows matching.
2. Reach into the other table in a very efficient way, namely via the PK.
3. Grab the other columns needed.
4. Sort to achieve the `ORDER BY`.
5. Peel off `LIMIT` rows.

There is no further optimization.  A possible drag on things is if `*` includes some bulky `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns.

Comment: I tried this, but then it will just use the `PRIMARY` and the `key_len` will be 4 again. Also in terms of query performance there is no difference.

Comment: Oh, and it is not the case that the relationship is one-to-one between A and B, unfortunately.

Comment: @thijsvdp - I made several changes to my Answer.  Bottom line:  You seem to be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. Actually in the real use case I am filtering records in B, using a full text index. However,  I did not include that here as the results were the same and it overcomplicates the question. Could it be that it has something to do with the selectivity? Both `language_id` and `result_id` don't have too many distinct values...

Comment: Do _not_ expect the advice here to apply if there is more filtering, especially FULLTEXT !  The Optimizer will almost always do the FT filtering _first_, regardless of the rest of the `WHERE`.  (I'm willing to tackle a more complex query.)

Comment: Ok let me prepare that example then. I will add the results as soon as possible. :)

Comment: @thijsvdp - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that this was as much optimization as possible. Then I probably have to find other solutions to restrict the number of records returned by the filter.

Comment: @thijsvdp - When the FT returns a few rows, the query will be fast.  When it returns hundreds of rows, the query will be slow.  In the latter case, my question about `*` and `TEXT` can lead to some improvement -- by postponing the fetching of those columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am considering performing a subquery on B with a `LIMIT` of say 10000, which forces the query to only `ORDER BY` on 10000 records max. This will be performant. The query serves a front-end application, and I don't expect someone going through so many records ever anyways.

Comment: @thijsvdp - Consider providing that in an Answer.  (It is OK to "self-answer" on this site.)

Comment: Yes will do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As Rick James mentioned, the query seems to be optimized as it is. The main problem here is that the resultant set of records (after filtering using the `FULLTEXT` index) is large. The sort will not happen using the indexes, because the `PRIMARY` key has been used to join table B on table A.

Because of this, I opted for another solution; limiting the number of records returned from B, such that the sort will only happen on this subset. This solution is reasonable for my use case, because my query serves a front-end application, where it is unlikely that the user will iterate through more than a couple of thousand records anyways. The `LIMIT` can be set loosely such that it is highly unlikely that a user will ever reach the end, unless the provided filter criteria will be so tight that the user will find all records meeting his/hers criteria.

The query will therefore be:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE A.*
FROM
    t_patent_documents A INNER JOIN
    (SELECT publication_id FROM t_inv_title_int_content_combined WHERE MATCH(invention_title) AGAINST("+hydraulic" IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10000) B on A.publication_id = B.publication_id
ORDER BY
    A.language_id ASC,
    A.result_order DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This performs like a charm.